# DELAYLOAD gives linking error in Qt LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to use `DELAYLOAD` flag in Qt creator. Here is minimal code which explains my problem:
In `pro` file:

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = DelayLoad
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG+=qwt

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../qwt-6.1.2/lib/ -lqwt
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../qwt-6.1.2/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../qwt-6.1.2/include

win32: QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += /DELAYLOAD:qwt.dll
```

In `mainwindow.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include "qwt_plot.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("replace by plot");
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(buttonClicked()));
    this->setCentralWidget(button);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::buttonClicked()
{
    QwtPlot *plot = new QwtPlot();
    this->setCentralWidget(plot);
}
```

This gives the following error:

> qwt.lib(qwt.dll):-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __delayLoadHelper2

I clicked several on `Run qmake`, `Clear`, `Rebuild`. That does not solve initial problem. I am using 'Qt 5.4.2' with `MSVC 2013 64 bit` compiler

Comment: You'll have to link delayimp.lib to get that symbol resolved.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks. I have added `win32:LIBS += "-LC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\amd64" -ldelayimp` line into `.pro` file. Now it works without linking errors

Comment: @Hans Passant  I also faced same issue. Using your suggested fix above, I got it resolved. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add following line into .pro file, that's right.

```
win32:LIBS += "-LC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\amd64" -ldelayimp
```